# Angular 2 - CWE Findings - jQuery and Mootools

Tags: angular

Recently, my company did a Source Code Analysis (using IBM AppScan) on my angular 2.0.0 project and a few vulnerabilities were flagged out. I've listed them below.

**Vulnerabilities**

CWE-79: Improper Neutralization of Input During Web Page Generation (Cross-site Scripting)

- MooTools Insecure Manipulation of Node
- JQuery Insecure Manipulation of Child Node

CWE-327: Use of a Broken or Risky Cryptographic Algorithm

- Insecure random number

CWE-311: Missing Encryption of Sensitive Data

- PostMessage To Any Target Origin
- Insecure HTTP Communication

Most of the vulnerabilities were from angular 2.0.0 library therefore there is nothing much that i can change to eliminate the vulnerabilites.

I understand from that angular 2 does not use jQuery or even MooTools. Is there an official source on this so that I can declare the findings as false positive?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed by email, these all seem to be false positives in IBM AppScan. Angular 2+ does not use MooTools or JQuery at all, does not contain any cryptography, and (from reading the source report), the insecure HTTP error is a false positive, too. AFAICT those were probably caused by running the security scanner over optimized / minified source code, which threw it off.